# Unhandled Exception: type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<QuizResultModel?>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the code for **quizResultModel**

```
quizResultModel = await (QuizService().saveAnswerFetchResult(
          widget.testPaperDetailsModel!.id,
          widget.packageId,
          answer,
          paperAttempt) as FutureOr<QuizResultModel?>);
```

here is code for Function **SaveAnswerFetchResult**

```
 Future<dynamic> saveAnswerFetchResult(
    String? testPaperId,
    String? programId,
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> answer,
    String? paperAttemptId,
  ) async {
    QuizResultModel? quizResultModel;
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> requestedData = {
        "action": actionforquizsavefetchresult,
        "answers": answer,
        "testPaper": testPaperId,
        "program": programId,
        "paper_attempt": paperAttemptId, //
      };
```

here is code for Function **FutureOr<QuizResultModel?>**

```
class QuizResultModel {
  String correctAnswers;
  String totalQuestions;
  bool isPass;
  bool isTimeUp;
  String skipped;
  String timeSpend;
  String? marksArchived;
  String? testType;
  String? totalMarks;
  String? message;
  QuizResultModel(
      {this.correctAnswers = "0",
      this.skipped = "0",
      this.isPass = false,
      this.isTimeUp = false,
      this.totalQuestions = "0",
      this.timeSpend = "0",
      this.marksArchived,
      this.testType,
      this.totalMarks,
      this.message});
  factory QuizResultModel.formMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    QuizResultModel quizResultModel = QuizResultModel(
        testType: map["test_type"],
        marksArchived: map["marks_archived"]?.toString() ?? "0",
        totalMarks: map["total_marks"]?.toString() ?? "0",
        message: map["message"]);
    return quizResultModel;
  }
}
```

there is problem between **SaveAnswerFetchResult** and **FutureOr**

Unhandled Exception: type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<QuizResultModel?>' in type cast

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to include a return statement in the function `SaveAnswerFetchResult`. This is causing it to return just Future whereas your code in the assignment to `quizResultModel` expects type `Future<QuizResultModel>` or `QuizResultModel`.

It is hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code, but you may also want to change the return type of `SaveAnswerFetchResult` to `Future<QuizResultModel?>` instead of `Future<dynamic>`. Then, remove the type cast to `FutureOr<QuizResultModel?>`.